# How to rename/mask actual Google Cloud Storage URL with my own applicaiton URL before view on applicaiton UI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, url, redirect, cloud, storage

I am reading files from Google cloud usign my web application where the actual patch is pointing to google. Instead I wanted to show hte file URL as my applicaiton URL. What is the best method to achieve this. I also requeust for inputs on how to ensure the file URL shown to user can not be opened directly throuhg browerset bypassing my web application.

Thanks in advance.

We have developed a web applicaiton that has its own database to store meta data but actual fileds are sored on Google Cloud Storage. Now the actual path of google cloud is getting displayed when I render a file. I need a solution to change the URL and file name and that should be vieweable within my application after authentication